# How can I get my Huawei E220 modem to work on this network?

Tags: modem, gsm

I recently purchased a Huawei E220 modem, which was branded by PhoneCompanyA, and I wish to use it on PhoneCompanyB's network using a SIM card from PhoneCompanyB. PhoneCompanyB's 3G network uses the 850MHz and 2100MHz bands, both of which this modem supports.

However when I try to use the modem, it will not connect to the network. When I try to do it manually with `AT+COPS=1,2,53000` I get `CME Error 30: No network service` which is odd because when I put the SIM card in my cell phone I get plenty of service.

Is there any way I can get this modem to work with this SIM card?

Comment: Has the the modem been 'rooted' or 'upgraded' with a custom firmware? Just because it's got a name on the box doesn't mean it's in the state at which it was manufactured!

Comment: I've upgraded the firmware to the latest available: 11.313.02.00.01 and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your command tries to connect specifically to a network with ID 53000.
Instead, try the following:

```
at+cops=0
```

According to various docs, this will allow the device to automatically select an appropriate network.

Comment: I've tried that. After performing this command, it connects to PhoneCompanyA's network, despite having PhoneCompanyB's SIM card. The network ID of PhoneCompnyB is 53000, hence why I used that value.

Comment: If it successfully connects to a network, it's allowed to use it. I don't see how that could be wrong. If you want further help, please name the two network operators in your question, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it connects to the network that I don't want to use: Vodafone New Zealand. I would like to use the Telecom New Zealand network.

Comment: According to [this list](http://www.numberportabilitylookup.com/networks?s), Telecom NZ has three different network codes. You might want to verify the correct SIM card is inserted.

Comment: Yep, I've tried all three of them, and neither of them work. The SIM card is definitely a Telecom NZ SIM card and works fine in my mobile phone.

Comment: I see. Well, I'm out of ideas, sorry. The last thing that comes to mind is SIM Lock, but that doesn't explain why a Telecom NZ card would allow you to connect to Vodafone NZ.